# Is there a test equivalent to a bachelor's degree?

Tags: degree, bachelor

Like the GED, which is equivalent to a high school degree, is there a test that you could obtain that is equal the a bachelor's degree? Which states in American can you take it? And what are the requirements? Is there a website? Please leave the link. Or is there some kind of online test that is equal to a bachelor's degree? If not, what would be the quickest way to get a bachelor's degree without going to college/University?
I want a bachelor's degree in Science, space science. I want to get a bachelor's degree quickly cause I feel as if I've wasted years of my life and want to get back on track. I want the bachelor's degree so I can go for a Master's degree.

Comment: Bachelor degree in what?- Science, Engineering, ...?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Most of the time, a bachelor alone won't help you if you haven't done the courses required for whatever you want to do with it afterwards.

Comment: It might actually be feasible to do this for a two-year degree. Some Community Colleges in the US will give you an Associate of Arts or Associate of Science degree in Liberal Arts or General Studies for taking a well-rounded set of General Education courses. Many of these General Education courses (e.g. Calculus I and II, French I, US History, Intro to Microeconomics, etc.) are ones for which Credit By Exam has long been available - a corresponding Associate's Degree Exam could consist of more or less having to take *all* or at least *most* of those exams in one swoop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there is not.

A bachelor's degree isn't a generic thing like a high school diploma.  For example, it makes a big difference what institution it's from and what your major was.  Unlike high school, in the US there aren't government-specified standards for what should be taught or tested for a college degree; each institution makes its own rules (usually under the oversight of accrediting organizations).  So there's no way that a standard test could substitute for a bachelor's degree in general.

There are some reputable colleges and universities that offer online degrees, but it involves a lot more than a single test.  You'd do roughly the same coursework as if you were physically attending the university, and you should expect it to take multiple years.

There are some disreputable "colleges" which will offer a degree based on a single exam, or your life experiences.  These are scams and their degrees are worthless.

Comment: "For example, it makes a big difference what institution it's from": I don't know about the US, but also at the high-school level there are big differences between institutions. In fact, when examining my students, I can frequently tell which type of high school they attended.

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining a bachelor's degree means that you have coped with the (at times arcane) requirements of an accredited academic institution. You have learned to read, understand, summarize, spell (we write out "you" and do not capitalize "university" in English), and write for a specific subject area. Some credits can be obtained online and there are a number of more or less dubious institutions that will certify credits for you as long as you pay them. But trying to just buy a sheepskin so that you get the job that requires a bachelor's degree will soon get you into hot water, as the employer will expect you to be able to work at the level of a bachelor.